# How to automatically adapt height of UITableViewCell containing a multiline UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

A subclass of `UITableViewCell` contains a `UIButton` with multi-line text, i.e. property `numberOfLines = 0`.

The table view cells vary in height, so the cell height is set to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

The cell height adapts when adding a `UILabel` with multiple text lines. However it does not adapt with a `UIButton`, in fact also the frame of the button does not adapt to the frame of its `titleLabel`.

What can I do to make the table view cell and its content view adapt to the button height?

```
class MyButtonCell: UITableViewCell {

    var button: UIButton!
    var buttonText: String?

    convenience init(buttonText: String?) {
        self.init()

        self.buttonText = buttonText

        button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
        button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
        button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .Center
        button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .Center

        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubView(button)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
            button.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.contentView.topAnchor),
            button.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.contentView.bottomAnchor),
            button.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.contentView.rightAnchor),
            button.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.contentView.leftAnchor)
            ])

        button.setTitle(buttonText, forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(buttonTextColor, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = buttonFont
    }
}
```

The cell height is calculated automatically with:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Example project on https://github.com/mtrezza/ButtonCellHeightBug

Filed Apple Bug Report #26170971.

The bug results in this:
[image]

Comment: Are you using storyboard and autolayout?

Comment: @Siriss I'm not using storyboard for this table view, although I'm using auto-layout for it in code (see line `NSLayoutConstraint`) above.

Comment: Got it. Try sizeToFit() on your button after you have set the text.

Comment: @Siriss Tried that without success :-/

Comment: are you dequeueing prototype cells, or are you creating a new cell for each indexPath?

Comment: @Siriss I'm not dequeueing the cells, the cells are in an array and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets the cell from the array based on the indexPath. Also it works fine if I add a `UILabel` with multilines as mentioned above, only the button is causing problems.

Comment: Did u find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath`. On your button, you can call `sizeToFit()`, which will resize it to contain the text.

Also, if you set the estimated size on the tableView (as you did), you usually don't need to call the `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, or `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath`, and the tableView will set it for you.

EDIT:

I created a test project, and you seem to be correct. Using a UIButton setTitle does not resize the cell.

A workaround, is to do the calculation using a label in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, and return that value + any padding. Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath, you can still set the title on the button and it will appear.

```
//paragraphs is just a string array.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,tableView.frame.width, <your prototype height>))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.text = paragraphs[indexPath.row]
        label.sizeToFit()
        print(label.frame.height)
        return label.frame.height
    }
```

Bug in iOS?

Comment: Both table view properties `estimatedRowHeight` and `rowHeight` have to be set for automatic cell height calculation. So because the property is not set, the method `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is overridden instead. The table view properties are interchangeable with the methods AFAIK. So this seems to be fine.

Comment: No a specified heightForRow will override tableview.estimatedRowHeight. If you set the estimated height on the tableView, you do not need to call either height or estimatedHeight delegate methods, as the tableView will handle it for you. You must use AutoLayout and have enough constraints set to give enough information to draw the cell.

Comment: Are you sure? The Apple does say: "To enable self-sizing table view cells, you must set the table view’s rowHeight property to UITableViewAutomaticDimension. You must also assign a value to the estimatedRowHeight property. As soon as both of these properties are set, the system uses Auto Layout to calculate the row’s actual height." https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html

Comment: That link says setting the rowHeight property on the tableView, not calling the heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate. Set the `tableView.rowHeight`, and `tableView.estimatedRowHeight` properties on the tableView and remove your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and see what happens. Also, I have never set the `tableView.rowHeight` property, and I have never had an issue before.

Comment: Thanks for your input so far. I found it is absolutely necessary to set both properties otherwise auto-resizing simply won't work, also the docs say that clearly. Also the properties and methods are interchangeable according to the docs, the only difference is performance implication to using `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` instead of `rowHeight`. And again, the cell heights are adapting correctly for UILabels and UIImageViews. I have this problem only with UIButton.

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts, I also assume it is a bug in iOS and will file a bug report with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Fully dynamic height for table view cell is achievable by 1) using estimated row height, 2) setting rowHeight to AutoDimension, 3) and *most importantly* using constraints in your xib/storyboard. The cell can contain buttons/labels or whatever UI components you'd like to have, as long as you constrain them properly, particularly to make sure things are constrained vertically so table view can figure out the cell height. And in this way you don't have to calculate height for dynamic text, no need for sizeToFit/sizeThatFit, and it works for different screen sizes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Siriss was able to reproduce my problem, see answer above. The table and cell in this case are not designed in storyboard but in code with auto-layout being used. The 4 necessary constraints for a single button in the table view cell are fairly simple, see above. Still the height is adapted fine for labels with multi-lines but not for buttons. I think this is because the text of a button is not set directly but with `setTitle:forState`, thus the label height constraints / frames are set too late and the cell's height is calculated based on a titleLabel without text.

Comment: Okay, now I see the difficulties. UILabel respects numberOfLines, but UIButton tends to be in a single line unless you do some calculations and set frame explicitly, which is tedious to do. If layout is a hurdle, just use a UILabel - it's much easier to layout correctly - and add a gesture recognizer to make it clickable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the internal `UIButtonLabel` resizes correctly, but the actual `UIButton` does not.

I've worked around this by extending `UIButton` and overriding a couple of things:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.titleLabel?.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.titleLabel?.frame.size.width ?? 0
}

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return self.titleLabel?.intrinsicContentSize ?? CGSize.zero
}
```

You'll also need to make sure that `titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0` and `titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I have also sometimes added my own height constraint tying the button height to the label height + a constant.